# Lebesgue integral of $f^{p}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$f : \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow [0,\infty], p\geq1$ show that:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f^p = p \int_0^\infty y^{p-1}m(\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: f(x)>y\})\,dy$.

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1254330/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this (general) identity for positive functions :

$\int_X f(x) d\mu = \int_0^{\infty} \mu( x\in X, f(x) > t) dt$

Comment: Correct! Never seen this identity before though.

Comment: Then you should try to demonstrate it if you're not supposed to know it ;)